# youtube-dl: use proxy on error

Tags: proxy, youtube

I'm using youtube-dl to download videos from youtube by playlists. Unfortunately, a ton of music videos are blocked in my country and youtube-dl spits out an error on those. There is the -i option to ignore errors, so the rest of the playlist works fine.

youtube-dl has also the --proxy option to specify a HTTP proxy, and it works great. The problem is that the most free proxy servers are really really slow, so long story short:

Is there a way to use only a proxy connection when the normal approach fails?

(... or does someone know fast, free HTTP proxys? ;) But I actually don't think they exist)

System info: Windows 7 + the youtube-dl windows build

Comment: I don't know how youtube-dl works, but you could do a script in (let's say python) and parse the output of the program. If the error occurs, you tell in your script to re-execute youtube-dl with the proxy this time, otherwise to continue without :) It's really pretty simple. Only thing to figure out is the correct REGEX!

Comment: Yeah, I think I'll have to do something like this. youtube-dl is actually written in python itself, so I might as well look into that. Just wondered if there is some simple way :)